# Apply DevExpress mask for string

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, input-mask

I'm using devexpress controlls for data entry in a C# desktop application. After the entry of validated text I am showing that data on separate asp.net web application.

I want to show the entered data with the same devexpress mask applied (as a format mask now). Therefore I am looking for something like

```
maskAppliedText = Foo.ApplyMask(<dev express mask>, <validated text>)
```

e.g.

```
Foo.ApplyMask("\A>LL--00", "ASD88")
```

Should return

```
ASD--88
```